# Alternative to "looping" in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've read that "if you are using loops in sql, you're probably doing it wrong", which led me here. Before the question though, some background on the scenario. I have the following database structure:

- "Users" has:

  - UserID int IDENTITY (PK)
  - Reliability float
- "UserSubmissions" has:

  - Value float
  - UserID int (FK) (PK)
  - SubmissionID (FK) (PK)
  - timestamp datetime (PK)
- "GlobalSubmissions" has:

  - IdealValue float
  - SubmissionID (PK)

Think of GlobalSubmissions as a table that contains the ideal values that ideally, users should submit. UserSubmissions is a table that contains the values submitted by users.

I have written a function that estimates a user's reliability by comparing a user's "submission"s to a single, specific "globalSubmission":

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetUserReliabilityForSubmission(@userID int, @submissionID int)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @userAverageValue float,
    @idealValue float;

    SET @userAverageValue = (
        SELECT AVG (Value)
            FROM UserSubmissions
        WHERE (UserID = @userID AND SubmissionID = @submissionID));

    SET @idealValue = (
        SELECT IdealValue
        FROM Submission
        WHERE (SubmissionID = @submissionID));

    RETURN 1 - ABS(@userAverageValue - @idealValue);
END
```

This works, but it calculates the reliability of a user based on only one specific submission ID. If I wanted to calculate the "global" reliability of the user, I need to use a loop to go through ALL distinct **SubmissionID** a user has ever submitted and run the procedure on it.

Is there a good alternative to using a loop in this case?

Comment: Does the procedure return what you expect? I have a slight doubt about the use of `@submissionID` in the `WHERE (UserID = @userID AND SubmissionID = @submissionID)` condition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT d.UserID, 1 - AVG(ABS(d.avg - d.IdealValue))
FROM (
  SELECT us.UserID, gs.SubmissionID, gs.IdealValue, AVG(us.Value) as avg FROM UsersSubmissions us
  JOIN GlobalSubmissions gs ON gs.SubmissionID = us.SubmissionID
  GROUP BY us.UserID, gs.SubmissionID, gs.IdealValue) d
GROUP BY d.UserId
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d880/8

However, I would say it's not great way of defining reliability. I think you should consider changing it to something like that:

```
SELECT d.UserID, 1 - AVG(ABS(d.avg - d.IdealValue) / ABS(d.IdealValue))
FROM (
  SELECT us.UserID, gs.SubmissionID, gs.IdealValue, AVG(us.Value) as avg FROM UsersSubmissions us
  JOIN GlobalSubmissions gs ON gs.SubmissionID = us.SubmissionID
  GROUP BY us.UserID, gs.SubmissionID, gs.IdealValue) d
GROUP BY d.UserId
```

And and example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d880/14

What is the change? It takes the *mistake* relatively to the value itself. There is a difference between saying *x = 5*, when it's actually *6* and saying *x = 500* when it's *501*.